# Appium giving error when opening app with robot framework

Tags: robotframework, appium-android

So here is my code I see the app open in the emulator then close and I still get this error

```
** Variables ** 
${REMOTE_URL} http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
${PLATFORM_NAME_ANDROID} Android
${DEVICE_NAME_ANDROID} emulator-5554
${APP_ANDROID} /Users/william_flow/Documents/Code/xxx/App/base.apk
${APP_PACKAGE} com.xxx.android
${AUTOMATION_NAME} appium
${RESET_OFF} true
${AppAct} com.xxx.android.flavor.full.activities.HomeActivity

** Test Cases *
Open Android app
Open Application ${REMOTE_URL} app=${APP_ANDROID} 
automationName=${AUTOMATION_NAME} 
platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME_ANDROID} 
deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME_ANDROID} appPackage=${APP_PACKAGE} 
noReset=${RESET_OFF}
sleep 5s
```

I run it I see it run in my simulator and it Fails saying

```
Open Android app | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred 
while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 
‘com.xxx.android’ application. Visit 
https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running- 
appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original 
error: ‘com.xxx.android.activities.MainActivity’ or 
‘com.xxx.android.com.xxx.android.activities.MainActivity’ never 
started. Visit 
https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running- 
appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting
```

so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you visit the page that it suggest you visit?

Answer (score 0):

I have modfied your code, so that it becomes more redable and get executed easily

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    This script starts apps on two phones
Library          AppiumLibrary
Library          Collections

*** Variables ***
${REMOTE_URL}  http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
${PLATFORM_NAME_ANDROID}  Android
${DEVICE_NAME_ANDROID}  emulator-5554
${APP_ANDROID}  /Users/william_flow/Documents/Code/xxx/App/base.apk
${APP_PACKAGE}  com.xxx.android
${AUTOMATION_NAME}  appium
${RESET_OFF}  true
${AppAct}  com.xxx.android.flavor.full.activities.HomeActivity

*** Test Cases ***
First test case
    Open Android app

*** Keywords ***
Open Android app
    Open Application  ${REMOTE_URL}  app=${APP_ANDROID}  automationName=${AUTOMATION_NAME}  platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME_ANDROID}  deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME_ANDROID}  appPackage=${APP_PACKAGE}  noReset=${RESET_OFF}  appActivity=${AppAct}
    sleep 5s
```

**Couple of Key points**

1. **appActivity** was missing
2. Assuming **appium server** is running at 4723
3. Assuming **Appium library** is installed
4. You may also want to have a look on this link [Automating mobile App using Robot Framework and Appium](https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/08/21/first-automation-script-using-robot-framework/)

If you can address above 4 points , your error should get resolved!!